# What form does the multiplication operator take in the spectral theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Reed & Simon give the following version of the spectral theorem (Theorem VII.3):

> Let $A$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator on $H$, a separable Hilbert space. Then, there exist measures $\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^N$ ($N = 1, 2, \ldots$ or $\infty$) on $\sigma(A)$ and a unitary operator $$U: H \rightarrow \bigoplus_{n=1}^N L^2(\mathbb{R}, d\mu_n)$$ so that $$(UAU^{-1} \varphi)_n(\lambda) = \lambda \varphi_n(\lambda)$$ where we write an element $\varphi \in \bigoplus_{n=1}^N L^2(\mathbb{R}, d\mu_n)$ as an $N$-tuple $$(\varphi_1(\lambda), \ldots, \varphi_N(\lambda)).$$ This realization of $A$ is called the spectral representation.

According to this theorem, every bounded self-adjoint operator is unitary equivalent to the map $$\varphi(x) \mapsto x\varphi(x).$$

However, in other versions of the theorem I have come across (for example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Multiplication_operator_version)) the multiplication operator is more general than multiplication by the identity function. Instead, we have that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to an operator $T_f$ whose action is $$\varphi(x) \mapsto f(x)\varphi(x).$$

Which is the correct form? Are they equivalent?

Comment: In the first form multiplication by $x$ you're only guaranteed that there is a direct sum such that $A$ acts as multiplication by $x$ on each summand individually.  In the second form multiplication by $f(x)$ there is just one summand.  There's no guarantee $A$ can be represented as multiplication by $x$ on just one summand.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thank you, your comment is very helpful.